# Excel VBA named range error subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to populate a combobox with the values from a named range, which I've created before on a sheet named "shComboBoxes",  and getting the error: "Subscript out or range".
When I test for the named ranges:

```
    For Each tempname In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        MsgBox (tempname.Name)
    Next
```

I can see the created named ranges, but using:

```
    For Each tempname In shComboBoxes.Names
        MsgBox (tempname.Name)
    Next
```

I get nothing back and therefor the error "subscript out of range" trying to use the function ("tblInstance" is one of the named ranges):

```
Public Function GetInstance() As Variant
    GetInstance = shComboBoxes.ListObjects("tblInstance").DataBodyRange.Value
End Function
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: no, I've checked the ranges in the name manager and both stand for: Scope Workbook.

Comment: If they're workbook-scoped, then as expected, `For Each tempname In shComboBoxes.Names` returns nothing.

Comment: Note that `ListObjects` are tables, (e.g. created with Ctrl+T). So sounds like you have no table named "tblInstance" on that sheet. A named range is not equivalent to a table.

Comment: If you have a named range, then `shComboBoxes.Range("tblInstance").Value`.